# When editing UITableView how to prevent that delete button from poping out?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Usually when user click delete button in edit mode of UITableView a delete button will pop up asking for confirmation.

I don't want that.

How do I get rid that confirmation ritual?

[image]

I want my delete button to work like the plus button. Just add. Just delete. No need to confirm. At least not when the stake is low like in one issue of my program where deleting will simply flag the table to be invisible when out of edit mode.

Answer (score 5):

Delete confirmation popup is not built into UITableView or UITableViewCell (swipe to delete functionality). Such a thing has to be manually added, therefore getting rid of it is easy: don't add a popup :)

If you are maintaining someone else's code, search for this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return isEditable ? YES : NO;
}
```

Method documentation says:

> The method permits the delegate to exclude individual rows from being treated as editable. Editable rows display the insertion or deletion control in their cells. If this method is not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable. Rows that are not editable ignore the editingStyle property of a UITableViewCell object and do no indentation for the deletion or insertion control. Rows that are editable, but that do not want to have an insertion or remove control shown, can return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone from the tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method.

Here's a link to Apple docs [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) for more complicated cases.

Comment: You sure? I do want to see the - and plus sign on the left. I just do not want user to do the extra step of deleting the row for low risk operation.

Comment: Ups, totally missed the question! That popup you mention is not there by default, it's manually added inside method I mentioned (or elsewhere following that method).

Comment: That's fine +1 nevertheless. I learn something new. Where is it added?

Comment: If you are maintaining old project, run the app, make popup appear and then search for the displayed text string from source code. Or you could search for UIAlertView

Comment: not that popup. It's the red delete button when you press delete.

Comment: Ok, now we're back to start.. my answer would be again that this confirmation dialog is built-in. Sigh. I'll add a link to Apple docs :) Think I was talking about swipe-to-delete, which doesn't have default popup, while you talk about pressing visible delete button..

Comment: Yea I don't want that visible Delete button. Just delete. Why confirm first?

Answer (score 2):

What is your data source?  If it's an array, why don't you remove the selected item from the array and then refresh the uitableview?